# How do you fix "configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables" on cygwin when building OpenJDK 15

Tags: java, windows, visual-studio, cygwin, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to build OpenJDK 15 on Windows. I'm running Windows 10, the latest Cygwin, and Visual Studio 2019. I followed this [build instruction](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk15u/blob/master/doc/building.md), and the configure script is telling me that my compiler can't create executables.

```
configure: Using default toolchain microsoft (Microsoft Visual Studio)
checking for link.exe... /usr/bin/link.exe
checking if the first found link.exe is actually the Cygwin link tool... yes
configure: Found Visual Studio installation at /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community using well-known name
configure: Found Microsoft Visual Studio 2019
configure: Rewriting VS_ENV_CMD to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/vc/auxiliary/build/vcvarsx86_amd64.bat"
configure: Trying to extract Visual Studio environment variables
configure: Setting extracted environment variables
checking for Visual Studio variables... ok
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/vc/tools/msvc/14.26.28801/atlmfc/include"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/vc/tools/msvc/14.26.28801/include"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/netfxsdk/4.8/include/um"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/include/10.0.18362.0/ucrt"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/include/10.0.18362.0/shared"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/include/10.0.18362.0/um"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/include/10.0.18362.0/winrt"
configure: Rewriting ipath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/include/10.0.18362.0/cppwinrt"
configure: Rewriting libpath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/vc/tools/msvc/14.26.28801/atlmfc/lib/x64"
configure: Rewriting libpath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/microsoft visual studio/2019/community/vc/tools/msvc/14.26.28801/lib/x64"
configure: Rewriting libpath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/netfxsdk/4.8/lib/um/x64"
configure: Rewriting libpath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/lib/10.0.18362.0/ucrt/x64"
configure: Rewriting libpath to "/cygdrive/c/progra~2/windows kits/10/lib/10.0.18362.0/um/x64"
checking for cl.exe... /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX86/x64/cl.exe
configure: Rewriting CC to "/cygdrive/c/PROGRA~2/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.26.28801/bin/HostX86/x64/cl"
checking resolved symbolic links for CC... no symlink
configure: Using microsoft C compiler version 19.26.28806 [Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.26.28806 for x64]
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/cygdrive/c/openjdkbuildatmp2/jdk15u':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
configure exiting with result code 77
```

I don't know where I messed up. I set up my build environment properly, with the required Cygwin packages, and Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. The only deviation from build instructions I made is running Cygwin shell as admin. Also, I have both Cygwin and MinGW installed, can this be the problem?

EDIT: Here's my [config.log](https://gist.github.com/jessielesbian/a802b08a89b8627decf4e9a05d7e5fda)

Comment: The error says "see config.log for more details". Can you please show those details?

Comment: I added that in an edit.

Comment: It seems the paths to VS and the SDK have spaces and are not quoted. You can see in the log file that it's trying to run the compiler from inside the VS directory but failing with half the path (up to the first space), stating it's a directory (because `C:\program~2\Microsoft` exists too). Not sure how to fix this though, but it may point you in the right direction nonetheless...